# Bluetooth turns on instead of WIFI

Tags: networking

I have Dell inspiron laptop.

And I recently installed 14.04.
And whenever I press the hardware button provided for WiFi, bluetooth turns on.

And I used command sudo service wireless start.
this was the reply "wireless: unrecognized service"

What do i do?